# Longtable breaks PDFtex output with table in fancyhdr header

Tags: pdftex, longtable, csvsimple

I'm having an issue where if the table I pull using csvsimple is too long, the PDF won't build. BUT this is only an issue if my fancyhdr header has a table of any kind in it. If you take 20 or so lines out of the parts_list_test.csv it builds correctly. Here is the relevant code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Header and Footer package
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=2cm,headheight=70pt]{geometry} % Necessary for footer to stay on page
\geometry{letterpaper, portrait}
\usepackage{array} % Required for table typesetting
\usepackage{csvsimple} % Necessary for importing .csv files
\usepackage{longtable} % Required for tables spanning multiple pages
\usepackage{datatool} % Imports .xls files for use in Latex
\DTLloaddbtex{\PL}{./Resources/parameters.dbtex} % *NOTE* USE CORRECT .dbtex LOCATION, also \PL callout is arbitrary, just ensure it is nominal throughout the document
\usepackage{lastpage} % Required to show X of X pages in footer

\setlength{\headheight}{70pt} % NOTE distance here must match distance set above

\begin{document}

\DTLassign{\PL}{1}{\article=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{2}{\rev=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{3}{\docno=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{4}{\docdate=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{5}{\stcholder=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{6}{\makemodel=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{7}{\stcno=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{8}{\projno=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{9}{\preby=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{10}{\insa=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{11}{\insb=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{12}{\insc=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{13}{\insd=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{14}{\inse=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{15}{\insf=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{16}{\insg=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{17}{\insh=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{18}{\insi=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{19}{\insj=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{20}{\insk=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{21}{\insl=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{22}{\insm=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{23}{\insn=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{24}{\inso=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{25}{\insp=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{26}{\insq=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{27}{\insr=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{28}{\inss=var}
\DTLassign{\PL}{29}{\inst=var}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Header & Footer
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes lines under header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes lines above footer

\chead{
        {\Large\bfseries\stcholder \\}
        {\large\bfseries\makemodel \\}
        {\large\bfseries SPECIAL HARDWARE PARTS LIST AND INSTRUCTIONS \\}
        {\begin{center} 
        \csvreader[tabular=|c|c|c|c|,
        table head=\hline\bfseries REVISION & \bfseries DRAWING NUMBER & \bfseries PREPARED BY & 
\bfseries DATE
        \\\hline, late after line=\\\hline,] 
        {header_rev_log_test.csv}{}
        {\csvlinetotablerow}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{-10mm} % Brings Parts List table closer to header
        }
        }
\cfoot{
        {\large\bfseries\docno \\}
        {\bfseries SPECIAL HARDWARE PARTS LIST AND INSTRUCTIONS \\}
        {\bfseries\docdate \ REV \rev \\}
        Page \thepage \hspace{0pt} of \pageref{LastPage}
        }
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Parts List
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}

{\bfseries\large PARTS LIST}
\csvreader[longtable=
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{11mm} % ITEM
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{25mm} % PART NUMBER
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{25mm} % EQ. PART NUMBER(S)
    |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{54mm} % DESCRIPTION
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{12mm} % NOTE
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{22mm}|, % UNITS PER ASSY
    table head=\hline
    \bfseries ITEM &
    \bfseries PART NUMBER & 
    \bfseries EQ. PART NUMBER(S) &
    \bfseries DESCRIPTION &
    \bfseries NOTE &
    \bfseries UNITS PER ASSY
    \\\hline\endhead,
    late after line=\\\hline,]
    {parts_list_test.csv}{}
    {\csvlinetotablerow}
\end{center} 

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Here is the error log

```
]
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> \egroup 

l.106   {\csvlinetotablerow}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{longtable} on input line 106 ended by \end{tabular}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.106   {\csvlinetotablerow}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.106   {\csvlinetotablerow}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{longtable} on input line 106 ended by \end{center}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.107 \end{center}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[2] [3] 
AED: lastpage setting LastPage
[4]

! LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 86 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.162 \end{document}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the link to the .csv files https://github.com/megacorvega/latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Unfortunately, your issue is not reproducible without `header_rev_log.csv`  and `parts_list.csv`.

Comment: @leandriis Ah of course, I just added dummy .csv files that reproduce the issue, and updated the code to reflect the file name changes.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the `\csvreader` call in the header. Replacing that with a standard `tabular` fixes the issue. I do not know what the reason is though...

Comment: @wimi Yep, I was able to get it to build with just `tabular` for once as well. I must have screwed something up trying that before. I'm gonna call that the solution and just use DTLassign to get the variables in the table. Thanks for the help!